# Webview works in ICS but not Gingerbread

Tags: android, authentication, webview

I have an application that mostly is a webview that will try to connect to my companies webpage. The page is an https and requires authentication. The current code that I'm using works when I'm running on a device or emulator which has ICS, but it does not work on 2.3.3. I've tried building it for 2.3.3, this version has been tested on both 2.3.3 and 4.x and only works on ICS. So it doesn't matter if I build it for ICS or Gingerbread.

I've tried different solutions to similar problems, but I'm not able to get it to work.

BrowserActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
   mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
   mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   ...
   mWebView.loadUrl(urlString); //urlString is an https site
}
```

My webclient class:

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient{
   public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm){
      handler.proceed(username, password);
   }
   public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){           
      handler.proceed();
   }
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
      super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
   }
}
```

This is the basic content of my application. I've tried logging in the different callbacks and I'm not getting any SSL error or an "regular" error. The only thing I see in my logcat is that when I'm running on Gingerbread the `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` is called over and over again. I've checked to see that the credentials are correct and they are. I can also mention that I've got `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` in my manifest.

I've checked with the IT department to see if the server is using [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) but they are telling me that it ain't using it.

Is there anyone that knows a reason to why this doesn't work? As mentioned earlier, it seems as the authentication doesn't work for some reason, as I see the `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` being called over and over again in Gingerbread.

The problem is that the page doesn't load, the webview stays blank.

Comment: Getting the same issue on Froyo and Gingerbread. Not even loading SSL, just local HTML data. You ever resolve this?

Comment: No, I have stopped working on this project.

Comment: I found out this odd behaviour was happening while setting a background image to the WebView (not via HTML, from a resource).